# atomic orbital probability graph for p and s orbitals

Tags: orbitals

In the probability density graphs of s and p and even other orbitals start from nucleus as shown in the picture given below

[image]

they all start from nucleus i.e. there is good probability of electrons of the particular orbitals being there.

my doubts:

1. there is proper energy variation and differences of energies of electrons being in particular orbital, example, energy of 2p will be greater than 2s etc. and as i think energy of electron is due to its position with respect to nucleus. as in the diagram probability regions of 1s 2s and 2p is same {though value of y coordinate is small}
   then how can there energies be different?
2. don't the electron clouds of 1s , 2s , 2p intermix? moreover electron cloud- a 3D SPACE which must be wide enough to get electrons at different distances from nucleus doesn't violate the rule that electron has one constant energy in one orbital.

Comment: Energy is associated to the orbital not to a specific r